# HTML5 pattern - dont allow the following characters

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I want to block the following characters:

```
( 
) 
/ 
> 
< 
] 
[ 
\ 
" 
, 
; 
|
```

What is wrong with my pattern?

```
pattern="[^()/<>[]\,'|\x22]+"
```

Comment: how do you use the pattern?

Comment: Is it returning false positives or negatives? If so which characters? Try posting your code. Straight away I think you need to escape quite a few characters.

Comment: @ste-fu Post what code? He has posted it. He posted the `pattern` attribute. What characters do you think he needs to escape?

Comment: You could have tested this trivially with any regexp testing site, which would have pointed out your error.

Answer (score 11):

> What is wrong with my pattern?

It contains a negated character class where you failed to escape a `]` symbol. *Inside a character class*, it *must be escaped in JS, *outside of a character class*, you *do not have to escape it*. Thus, your `"[^()/<>[]\,'|\x22]+"` pattern actually means: match one **and only one!** character other than `()/<>[` (with the `[^()/<>[]` part) followed with a *sequence of `,'`, **-OR-** (as `|` is an alternation operator if not escaped outside of a character class) a double quote (matched with `\x22`) followed with one or more literal `]` symbols (as `]` matches a literal `]` outside of a character class, and `+` is a quantifier set to it.

You actually need

```
pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+"
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<input name="name1" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+" placeholder="New value" title="No special characters!">
<input class="submit" value="Submit!" type="submit" name="name2">
</form>
```

Inside a character class, besides `]`, you need to escape the `\` symbol. And a `-` if it stands between two literal symbols, but you have no hyphens here.

Note: [HTML5 pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) value is anchored by default, i.e. the whole pattern is wrpapped into `^(?:` and `)$`. You do not have to put `^` and `$` between the pattern.

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

Answer (score 3):

you pattern contains a `]`, you should escape it using a `\`, other characters also need to be escaped, like the `\` when not used in the context of escaping another value:

```html
<form><input pattern="[^()/<>[\]\\,'|\x22]+"><input type=submit value=test></form>
```

Comment: great thanks :)   regarding this area: |\\x22 the first '\' is for '|\' so for what is the second '\' is used for?

Comment: It was left after testing the code, when testing the code it didn't work, so I tried that, but the cause was that I forgot to run the code, will remove it.

Comment: Looks like some characters are still missing :) BTW, a comma does not need escaping. Well, the `"[^()/<>[\]\,'|\x22]+"` answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `[a|b]` which works using the `RegExp` function but when using the html5 pattern attribute, if you aren't using number or string ranges like `[0-9]` or `[a-z]` then it seems to only accept parentheses, e.g. `(a|b)`

**TLDR**: instead of `[a|b]` USE: `(a|b)` if it's not a range.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the code below:

```
emailPattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```